# $\beta:I\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{E}^3$ an arc length parameterized curve, how can I prove following statements:

Tags: euclidean-geometry, arc-length, frenet-frame

We know that:
$$\beta:I\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{E}^3$$ is an arc length parameterized curve
with $$\forall s\in I:\kappa(s)\neq0 \wedge \tau(s)\neq0$$
And knowing that:
$$\Vert\beta(s)\Vert=const.$$

a) how can I prove that $\beta(s)\bullet\beta’(s)=0\space(\forall s\in I)$

*So far I came up with, that $\Vert\beta(s)\Vert=const. \implies \beta’(s)=0$* is this correct or am I here mistaken?

b)prove that there exist functions $\lambda(s),\mu(s):\beta(s)=(\lambda(s)\bullet N(s)+\mu(s)\bullet B(s)$

*how could I best do this? I thought so far, N and B are linearly independent, and form a positive basis, and because $T_{\beta}=\beta’=0\space \forall s \in I$ We can describe $\beta$ entirely by N and B, but how do I get to $\lambda(s)$ and $  \mu(s)$?

Thank for any help already in advance.

Comment: If a particle travels (with undetermined speed) along a circle centered at the origin, do you conclude that its velocity must be $0$? The unit tangent vector cannot be the $0$ vector, by the way. Go back to basics.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for the picture in my head. Now it is clear to me. Can I make the assumtion in my proof, that $\beta(s)= \left(Rcos\left(\frac{s}{R}\right),Rsin\left(\frac{s}{R}\right)\right)$ the only curve which satisfies these properties, and use this?

Comment: No, because we’re talking about space curves, not planar curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

For part (a) consider taking the derivative of $\|\beta(s)\|^2 = k$ for some constant $k$.

For part (b), take a look at the Frenet-Serret formulas.

Comment: I'm taking the liberty of replacing your $\beta(s)^2$ with $\|\beta(s)\|^2$. Although some people write $v^2$ for $\|v\|^2$, it is mostly just very confusing. Do you also write $vw$ for $v\cdot w$?